# Performing if inside lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst = [('654', '2.12', '86'), ('2', '756'), ('5', '1.77', '71'), ('1.65', '55')]
```

The function

```
num = min(lst,key=lambda x: abs(float(x[1]) - 2))
```

looks up each number at position `x[1]` inside each tuple and outputs the tuple where `x[1]` is the closest to 2. Is it possible to adjust the function so that it looks up only tuples with `len == 3`?

And if it's so I want then to output that tuple and the following 2-item one at the same time. E.g. for the above the final result should be:

`[('654', '2.12', '86'), ('2', '756')]` and with this I think the for loop will be enough so I think I'll manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list always alternates between 3-tuple and 2-tuple, you could use

```
zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)
```

to [group the items into pairs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). Then you can use `min` essentially as you had before:

```
In [39]: min(zip(*[iter(lst)]*2),key=lambda (x,y): abs(float(x[1]) - 2))
Out[39]: (('654', '2.12', '86'), ('2', '756'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas can only hold expressions, so you are limited to ising a conditional expression:

```
lambda x: abs(float(x[1]) - 2) if len(x) == 3 else float('inf')
```

but that'll only return a 3-element tuple. The `key` function can only ever take *one* element in the sequence into account.

If you *always* have a 2-element tuple following your 3-element tuples, you'd need to group them together, then determine the minimum from among those paired tuples (as unutbu's answer does).

Comment: This returns a value even if no element has `len == 3`.

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, I was unaware of that one (don't use floats that much); it has the advantage of not requiring an import of `sys`.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list using a generator expression:

```
num = min((t for t in list if len(t) == 3), key=lambda x: abs(float(x[1]) - 2))
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing `()` around the generator

Answer (score 1):

You can just:

```
num = min([el for el in lst if len(el)==3], key=lambda x: abs(float(x[1]) - 2))
```

And this highlights the problem, you are using heterogenous data in your list. If all the tuples are not  the same thing they probably don't belong to the same list.